# Simple Xpath puzzle

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to automate the Google Translate web interface with Selenium (but it's not necessary to understand Selenium to understand this question, just know that it finds elements and clicks them). I'm stuck on selecting the language to translate from.

I can't get to the point where the drop-down menu opens, as seen in the screenshot below.

Now, I want to select 'Japanese'.

This xpath expression works: `$b.find_element(:xpath,"//*[@id=':13']/div").click` But I would rather have one where I can just input the name of the language.

This xpath expression also works: `$b.find_element(:xpath,"//*[contains(text(),'Japanese')]").click` But only as long as there is no other 'Japanese' text on the page.

So I'm trying to narrow down the scope of my xpath, but when I try to specify the path to take to find the 'Japanese' text, the expression no longer works, I can't find the element: `$b.find_element(:xpath,"//*div[@id='gt-sl-gms']/*[contains(text(),'Japanese')]").click`

It also no longer works for the original xpath either: `$b.find_element(:xpath,"//*div[@id='gt-sl-gms']/*[@id=':13']/div").click`
Which is weird, because to bring down the drop-down menu, I use this xpath `$b.find_element(:xpath,"//*[@id='gt-sl-gms']/*[contains(text(),'From:')]").click`.

So it's not that I have two wildcards in my expression and it's not that my expression is too specific. There's something else that I'm missing and I'm sure it's really simple.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Edit** Other things I have tried unsuccessfully:

`$b.find_element(:xpath,"//*/div[@id='gt-sl-gms']/*[@id=':13']/div").click`
`$b.find_element(:xpath,"//*[@id='gt-sl-gms']/*[@id=':13']/div").click`
`$b.find_element(:xpath,"//*[@id='gt-sl-gms']//*[@id=':13']/div").click`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the div with "@id=':13'" is an  **descendant** of the div with "@id='gt-sl-gms"  your xpaht `"//*[@id='gt-sl-gms']//*[@id=':13']/div"` would work. 
The above xpaht expect that the html looks somehow like:

```
<div id="gt-sl-gms">
    <div>
        <div id=":13">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If `<div id="gt-sl-gms">` in not an ancestor (as I expect) you have to look for an "real" ancestor, or you may use **following** (for nodes later in the document)  or **following-sibling** (for nodes later in the document at the same level as the previous.

Answer (score 2):

`*div` is incorrect, it should be just `div`. Also, depending on he structure of the HTML, you may need `//` instead of `/`.

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect your suggestions. Would you mind clarifying which `/` I should replace with `//`? Do you mean `$b.find_element(:xpath,"//*[@id='gt-sl-gms']//*[@id=':13']/div").click`, because I've tried that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting descendants (//) instead of (/*) which is really grandchildren or deeper.

Comment: Did you mean `$b.find_element(:xpath,"//*[@id='gt-sl-gms']//[@id=':13']/div").click`, because that I tried that Xpath as well and was also unsuccessful.